# AttributeError: 'Retry' object has no attribute 'method_whitelist'

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib3

The following error occurred while trying to run code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    response = session.post(base_url, params={'query': filename_query})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 805, in urlopen
    if retries.is_retry(method, response.status, has_retry_after):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in is_retry
    if not self._is_method_retryable(method):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 331, in _is_method_retryable
    if self.method_whitelist and method.upper() not in self.method_whitelist:
AttributeError: 'Retry' object has no attribute 'method_whitelist'
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know your specific case since there is not much info. Nevertheless, I had the same error while using the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package in an Apache Beam pipeline

The thing is that `method_whitelist` was deprecated and removed from `urllib3==1.26.0` onwards, as stated in the [release changelog](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#1260-2020-11-10)

The solution in my case was to set the `urllib` version to a previous one, adding `urllib3==1.25.11` to my `requirements.txt`

Comment: this is the best thing that has happened to me ever

Answer (score 3):

There was a similar problem for me. In my case, the problem was that the pyfcm library was not updated. This library is for sending push notifications. My problem was solved by updating this library.

```
pip install pyfcm --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `allowed_methods` instead of `method_whitelist`. The latter was removed at some point and was replaced by the former.

Comment: Here is a link that references the change - [https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#1260-2020-11-10](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#1260-2020-11-10)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by installing `requests==1.26.0` and `urllib3==1.26.2`.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `urllib3==1.25.11` , got rid of the whitelist problem.  Thank you