# Python Azure Functions libraries

Tags: python, azure-functions

I want to use some libraries in my Python Azure Function. I use requirements.txt for it. When I import them like this I get a 200 OK (when deployed to Azure & ran from there):

```
import databricks_cli
```

When I import them like this

```
import databricks_cli.sdk.api_client
import databricks_cli.unity_catalog.api
```

or this

```
from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.unity_catalog.api import UnityCatalogApi
```

I get a 500 error. I need to use certain objects from the libraries, so in this case for example the object `ApiClient`. I cannot do so with simply importing `databricks_cli`. How do I make this work?

EDIT:

Traceback of the error:
[image]

Requirements.txt:

[image]

When I try to install `databricks-cli-catalog` or `databricks-cli.catalog` I get the following error (also tried variations like `databricks-cli-unity-catalog` or `databricks-cli.unity-catalog`:
[image]

Comment: Please post the complete traceback you are getting.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I made an edit.

Comment: try installing - `pip install databricks-cli --upgrade` and you can also try - `pip install databricks-cli-uc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that during the deployment, `databricks-cli 0.8.7` got installed, while `0.17.6` is the latest version, and also the version I had installed locally. The solution to this was to put the latest version in `requirements.txt`. After fixing this issue, I got this error: `Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: type object 'Retry' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST'`. I thought I didn't use `Retry` anywhere in my code, however after exploring the files of the `databricks-cli` library, I saw that its `ApiClient` did. The solution to this was to set the version of `urllib3` to `1.25.11` in the `requirements.txt` as mentioned in this post: [AttributeError: 'Retry' object has no attribute 'method_whitelist'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289720/attributeerror-retry-object-has-no-attribute-method-whitelist)